# Limit User See Only Their Data [ Laravel ]

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I want to limit User to see only their data not Any Other data in laravel.

Ex. User `A` can see only data that User `A` was created And Cant See Any Data created by Other User.

**My Controller**

```
<pre>
    public function index()
    {
        $expense = Expense::with(['user'])->get();
        return ExpenseResource::collection($expense);
    }
</pre>
```

Thanks in advances..

Comment: Are you using the auth controller in your code?

Comment: Nope, its another controller  @farooq

Comment: Which data should be limited? For which model? Could you add more information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to have a `user_id` in your `expenses` table then in your `controller` you do this

`Expense::where('user_id', Auth::id())->with('user')->get();`

**Edit:**
However you may want to check laravel's [Global scope](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#query-scopes) or [Local scope](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#local-scopes)

Comment: Are u online, can u help me abit?

Comment: @CamBoKiDz any help needed?